# Query that shows data depending of 2 columns

Tags: sql-server, range

I'm working on a Report in Visual Basic. It has a query to show the information below.

So, I need a query that sets all the rows that are between 2 values that the user choose. The problem is that the value exists several times.

To explain better:

```
ID          Category_ID SubCategory_ID Description    Period_ID     Data
----------- ----------- -------------- ------------- -----------   --------
1           1           1              PRUEBA           1           100.00
2           2           5              Total            1           2.00
3           1           1              sgsdg            2           25.00
4           1           1              fsdf             2           5.00
5           1           1              sdf              2           54.00
```

There will be a lot more of Period_ID. So, if the user chooses Period 1 and Period 5, it will show all the data between Period 1 and Period 5 (i.e. Period1, Period2, Period3, Period4 and Period5).

Is there a query which can do this?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you want? If all you want is a filter on a range of periods then it is just WHERE Period_ID >= value1 and Period_ID <= value2

Comment: Please provide your table structure and define what is period? Your example doesn't show a column named period.

Comment: Google and learn about the WHERE clause in SQL.

Comment: Can you proved the query you have so far?

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that WHERE exists. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
Select * 
FROM SAMPLE_TABLE
WHERE SAMPLE_TABLE.PERIOD_ID
IN (SELECT ID FROM PERIOD
WHERE ID >= 1 AND ID <= 5)
```

This is called a subquery.  This relies on you have a period table, which I assume you have